# get numpy matrix rows have intersection with array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I have huge list of int32 numpy 1d arrays. Is there an efficient way to get indexes of rows having non-empty intersection with test array? Basically I'm looking for faster replacement for pythonic expression:

```
indexes = [
    i for i, n in enumerate(iterable_of_iterables)  # [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4]]
    if set(n).intersection(test_iterable)           # [1, 4]
]                                                   # -> [0, 2]
```

Comment: Those variable length lists makes it difficult to leverage NumPy.

Comment: They are just lists of hashed words. I can np.pad them to uniform length.

Comment: If you can, then it might be possible. Feel free to edit the question and show us the padded version.